# Buildup of Jquery animations on live event handler

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I am using the "live" technique in jquery to add icons on hover using the code below and on this site: http://vitaminjdesign.com/adrian/ :

```
$('a').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
      if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
            $('<a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.gif" class="facebook" alt="facebook"></a>').appendTo(this).fadeIn(500);
            $('<a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.gif" class="twitter" alt="twitter"></a>').appendTo(this).fadeIn(500);
      } else {
            $('a').find('.facebook,.twitter').fadeOut(500);
      }
});
```

This works perfectly, however there is a buildup of icons loading. Typically I use the .stop() command, but this isn't working, perhaps because I am using a live event handler? Any suggestions? Also, the icons don't seem to be fading in, just fading out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **.stop(true, true)** like so:

```
$('a').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
      if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
            $('<a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.gif" class="facebook" alt="facebook">    </a>').appendTo(this).fadeIn(500);
            $('<a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.gif" class="twitter" alt="twitter">    </a>').appendTo(this).fadeIn(500);
      } else {
            $('a').find('.facebook,.twitter').stop(true, true).fadeOut(500);
      }
});
```

[jQuery API - stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: The second true may not be needed

Answer (score 0):

try [clearQueue()](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/)

This should clear the queue of events.

Comment: right, clearQueue isn't limited to animations though, so it can be useful if you want to stop other events.